# Avoid concurrent access to same queue element

Tags: python, django

I'm reviewing/refactoring a queue that's going to be used internally by up to 20 people simultaneously but as of now, multiple people can access the first element ( We tried it locally clicking on the link at the same time. )

The flux is similar to this:

**views.py**

```
[GET]
def list_operator(request, id):
  if request.POST:
    utilitary = Utilitary(id)
    pool = ThreadPool(processes=1)
    async_result = pool.apply_async(utilitary.recover_people, (id, ))
    return_val = async_result.get()
    person = People.objects.get(pk=return_val)
    return redirect('people:people_update', person.pk)
```

**utilitary.py**

This file has the method `recover_people` which performs around 4-5 queries (where people have `flag_allocated=False`) across multiple tables and sorts a list, to return the first element.
The final step is this one:

```
for person in people:
  p_address = People_Address.objects.get(person_id=person.id)
  p_schedule = Schedules.objects.get(schedules_state=p_address.p_state)

  if datetime.now() > parse_time(p_schedule.schedules_hour):
    person = People.objects.get(pk=person.id)
    person.flag_allocated = True
    person.date_of_allocation = datetime.now()
    person.save()
    return person.pk
```

Perhaps something in the Utilitary method's logic is wrong? Or I should be expecting this problem with this amount of people simultaneously calling this method?

Could using a cache help? I'm sorry, I'm new to django and mvc.

Comment: It definitely sounds like a race condition to me.  They all run the same queries, get the same results, and do the same work very likely.  You might try thinking about some method to"register" a worker with each unit of work

Comment: @DanFarrell I am sorry, could you provide an example or a link? This is very new to me.

Comment: How is this a "queue" actually ?

Comment: See if my answer speaks to you

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers It's always the first element of the list.

Comment: Yes but your calls to `utilitary.recover_people` are not queued - they are ran by concurrent processes, and since `utilitary.recover_people` is not an atomic operation you do have a race condition indeed (two processes running `utilitary.recover_people` concurrently will select the same object).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers How do you personally deal with this kind of problem? Any tool you could recommend?

Comment: @Onilol this really depends on the project's specs, context, tools you already have installed for the project etc so I don't have a one-size-fits-all answers here, but the general principle is using a lock of some sort so you cannot have two concurrent invocations of `utilitary.recover_people` whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it seems like a lot to select the "person" in the database again just to lock it in memory and then write it to the database. This action is not atomic.

You can have the record locked by other process between these actions:

> ```
> person = People.objects.get(pk=person.id)
> person.flag_allocated = True
> person.date_of_allocation = datetime.now()
> person.save()
> ```

That is where your problem is. But... If you directly update the record on the database passing a condition on which the update will only write on a record where the `flag_allocated=False`, you just have to see if your update affected any row or not. If not, you go to the next person on the queue.

Something like:

```
for person in people:
    rows = People.objects.filter(pk=person.id, flag_allocated=False).update(flag_allocated=True)
    if rows:
        break # Got the person... And nobody else will.
```

The update will have the record locked to write it to the allocation_flag (SQL principle). If two updates try to mess with the same row, one will do it first and then the second won't update anything and will try the next person.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not doing anything to prevent interference between  concurrent processes, they're bound to step on each others' toes sooner or later.

A time honored approach to modeling a queue in a database is to register a worker to a particular job in a transactionally consistent manner before executing the job.

Say you have a table `work` with columns for a job id or specification, an initially null status, and an initially null value for worker.  The workers can "register" for a job by running an update such as

```
 Update `work` set worker = my_worker_id, status=initializing where status is null and worker is null limit 1.
```

Only one worker can " register" the next job due to the " where" clause.

This isn't perfect - you still have to handle jobs that were orphaned by a failed worker.  The status columns, updated on job completion, combined with a heart beat of some kind for the workers, and careful design around job idempotency, would give you the primitives to ensure jobs didn't get stuck on a failed or AWOL worker.

Comment: So perhaps something like Celery would help?

Comment: I would definitely recommend adding a queueing framework.  We've used celery at my job in the past and found it acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical solution here would be to use a lock of some sort so you cannot have two concurrent executions of `utilitary.recover_people` whatsoever - the function waits until it acquire the lock, executes, and releases the lock.

Given that Django is typically served by multiple processes (and you certainly don't want to change this), and that you don't want a screwed up call to keep the lock forever, a good solution here is to use something like redis to store the lock (all django processes sharing the same redis db of course), with an expiration set to a reasonable time so it won't remain set forever.

There are examples of such setups using celery (not that you necessarily needs celery here, it's just that the principle is the same since it's a common use case when using celery to avoid concurrent tasks stepping on each other).

You could also just use your SQL database to store the lock but then you don't have automatic expiration...

Comment: I use redis for queueing as well, and have found it to be a better fit than a relational database.